# Is there any way to reset @Environment object into it's defaults?

Tags: swiftui

I have a `class`, and I'm using it's `instance` in a view. I have included only 1 `@Published variable`, but it has many. So, I can't just set the values to defaults one by one. I want to `reset the instance` in the view to it's `defaults` before I set new values. My question is `how to reset` it in one go to `default values` stated in it's original class?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@EnvironmentObject private var Tools: Class1

    var body: some View {
        Button ("Reset") {

Tools.ResetToDefaults //pseudo code

}
             
    }
}


}


class Class1: ObservableObject {
    
        @Published var state: Bool
    
    init(state: Bool) {
        self.state = false
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Just create a method on `Class1` that sets the properties how you want.

Comment: ok thanks will do that